# OverFlow hidden showing incorrectly in different browsers

Tags: html, css

I have a div in which i am showing some text and the div has fixed height and width and overflow hidden. But it is showing different text in firefox, chrome and safari. In chrome and safari one extra line of text is visible.If i remove:

```
-moz-column-count:2;
-webkit-column-count:2;
```

property then its working fine in all. But if add this property the it showing different text in firefox and chrome.

I am attaching snapshot for chrome and firefox.

```
   <div style=" width: 710px; height: 70px;position:absolute;overflow:hidden;top=0;left=0;-moz-column-count:2;-webkit-column-count:2;z-index:102;">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
        <p> Vivamus mattis laoreet velit quis malesuada. Quisque tincidunt elit sit amet nibh volutpat id pretium nisl consequat. Quisque dictum lacus at mauris scelerisque auctor. Nulla adipiscing, sapien sit amet </p>

    </div>
```

**Chrome view** 
[image]

**Fire fox View**
[image]

Comment: If you normalize the CSS they look the same to me. BTW, why are you defining the z-index twice in your example?

Comment: I'm confused why you need the -moz-column-count:1 code if it works fine without it and you're using it to specify the default single-column layout anyway.

Comment: actualy its fine. your div is 710 pixels in width: so is the text. Chrome thinks there is nothing to hide because nothing is floating outside the div

Comment: I have to use  -moz-column-count:1 because the text can have multiple columns

Answer (score 0):

You should cut your height or Width tag from that DIV. Further P element needs some style to showing them as column.

```
<style type="text/css">
div {
    width: 710px; 
    position:absolute;
    overflow:hidden;
    top=0;
    left=0;
    -moz-column-count:2;
    -webkit-column-count:2;
    z-index:102;
}
p {
    overflow: hidden;
    float:left;
}
</style>  
<div>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
    <p> Vivamus mattis laoreet velit quis malesuada. Quisque tincidunt elit sit amet nibh volutpat id pretium nisl consequat. Quisque dictum lacus at mauris scelerisque auctor. Nulla adipiscing, sapien sit amet </p>

</div>
```

Comment: but i have to specify height for div